# update property in object loaded from js file - javascript

Tags: javascript, object

im very new in javascript and im trying to implement new function into existing project.
The background - 
In html file i can see:

```
<script src="js/users.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/seating-plan.js"></script>
```

File seating-plan.js access object stored in users.js that contains:

```
var users = [
    {"id": 1, "name":"first", "surname":"surname"},
    {"id": 2, "name":"second", "surname":"surname"}
]
```

**My question is:** Can I change a property loaded from such object so the file will be changed? If so how to do it? I read some posts how to change object property but such approach will only changed already loaded object, not rewrite js file so i would be stuck with same result after refresh. Im guessing I will need to change how I initially load array object but if you know how to do it with my original aproach or how to do the second option in easy way please assist. 
EDIT: localhost internal purpose (shared folder)

The approach I mentioned:

```
// Start of jQuery ready function
$(function () {

    //can already access object 
    for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {

        //example of how i tried to rewrite property
        if (users[i].id === 1){
            users[i].name = "NewName";
        }
    }
    .
    .
    .
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change data on the server, then you must send an instruction to the server to change the data.

It would be a serious security risk if, by default, any web browser could change data on any HTTP server. The Google homepage would be vandalised on a second-by-second basis if that were possible!

Typically this will be a POST request (which you could make with a `<form>` or with `XMLHttpRequest`/`fetch`).

You then need server-side code (written in the language of your choice) which will update the data.

Typically you will want to store the data in a database and generate `users.js` (although changing it to JSON would probably be a better idea) on demand.

Comment: Thanks for reply, i forgot to mention its localhost only - made an edit. Yeah i have seen that JSON is common loading object type, thank you!

Comment: @MartinVoroňák — That doesn't make a difference. Standard security rules and webserver capabilities are unchanged.